# codenameone cloudstorage commit

Tags: cloud, codenameone

[image]CloudObject cloudObject = new CloudObject("cloudData", CloudObject.ACCESS_PRIVATE);
        cloudObject.setString("name", "syww");
        cloudObject.setString("last", "lta");
        cloudObject.setIndexString(1, "kne");
        cloudObject.setIndexString(3, "ktwo");

```
    CloudStorage.getInstance().save(cloudObject);


    int responseCode = CloudStorage.getInstance().commit();
    if(responseCode != 0){
        Dialog.show("Error", "Error occured.", "Ok", null);
    }else{
        Dialog.show("Message", "Data is saved.", "Ok", null);
    }
```

when I try to commit ,it throws null pointer exception ,why?

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.codename1.cloud.CloudStorage$StorageRequest.buildRequestBody(CloudStorage.java:984)
    at com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest.performOperation(ConnectionRequest.java:318)
    at com.codename1.io.NetworkManager$NetworkThread.run(NetworkManager.java:261)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)

And when i have tested on real device it is working well so what is the problem ?
and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing a `CloudStorage` rollback before adding new elements, there might be some local changes that never made it to the server that need to be discarded.